# Spring @ConditionalOnBean not preventing bean from being created

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have several beans

#### AudioConfig.java

```
@ConstructorBinding
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "audio")
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@ConditionalOnProperty("audio.root-path")
public class AudioConfig {
    private final Path rootPath;
}
```

#### AudioFileProvider.java

```
@Component
@AllArgsConstructor
@Log4j2
@ConditionalOnBean(AudioConfig.class)
public class AudioFileProvider {
     private final AudioConfig audioConfig;
     ....
```

#### AudioCleanser.kt

```
@ConditionalOnBean(AudioFileProvider::class)
class AudioCleanser(
    private val dslContext: DSLContext,
    private val audioFileProvider: AudioFileProvider
)
```

So if my property audio.root-path is not defined then it should not try to instantiate AudioCleanser, right?

Yet I get :

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 1 of constructor in AudioCleanser required a bean of type 'AudioFileProvider' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'AudioFileProvider' in your configuration.
```

Comment: I have tried using all java classes as opposed to one in kotlin (AudioCleanser.kt) - issue is reproducible. 
Surprisingly, it is also observed that if you rename AudioCleanser to something else (say AudioXCleanser) so that it will appear later than others when sorted, you will not face issue.
Alternatively, if you can use @Configuration class to create beans and order AudioCleanser bean at the end, you won't face issue.
It (@ConditionalObBean) definitely has to do with the processing order of beans.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to try it out and for the insights !

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in several ways:

1. **Use all conditions in** `AudioCleanser`:

```
@ConditionalOnBean({AudioFileProvider::class,AudioConfig::class})
class AudioCleanser(
    private val dslContext: DSLContext,
    private val audioFileProvider: AudioFileProvider
)
```

2. **Use custom condition**:

```
public class AudioEnabledCondition extends AllNestedConditions {

    public AudioEnabledCondition() {
        super(ConfigurationPhase.REGISTER_BEAN);
    }

    @ConditionalOnBean(AudioConfig.class)
    static class AudioConfigExistsCondition {

    }

    @ConditionalOnBean(AudioFileProvider.class)
    static class AudioFileProviderExistsCondition {

    }

}

@Conditional(AudioEnabledCondition::class)
class AudioCleanser(
    private val dslContext: DSLContext,
    private val audioFileProvider: AudioFileProvider
)
```